# How to increase set of data by increment of 1 in excel?

Tags: excel

I have a set of data in excel, which varies in size, that I need to increment the final number by 1 each time I duplicate it. For example:

> 100065202-TR01
>   100065204-TR01
>   100018998-TR01
>   100065202-TR01
>   100065204-TR01
>   100018998-TR01
>   100065202-TR01
>   100065204-TR01
>   IB500-TR01
>   100005693-TR01
>
> 100065202-TR02
>   100065204-TR02
>   100018998-TR02
>   100065202-TR02
>   100065204-TR02
>   100018998-TR02
>   100065202-TR02
>   100065204-TR02
>   IB500-TR02
>   100005693-TR02

I need a way that I can increment `TR01`,`TR02`,`TR03`... up to TR20. The text before the `-TR**` will remain the same every time, I will simply be duplicating a (sometimes very large) block of data but want to change the final number each time.

Answer (score 1):

If you select the data you need and then "pull" to the right by clicking on the bottom right corner, where the black square is, it is done automatically by Excel.

See result

[image]